# Old URL resolved to a Wordpress page

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I have an URL indexed as `http://site_url/page_slug/downloads/file.pdf`.

That was a wrongly added relative path by some developer.

Now I have fixed the broken link but this URL in Wordpress internally resolves to `http://site_url/page_slug`

Not sure, what is wrong here, I re-saved the permalinks, but seems like `downloads/file.pdf` are being passed to `/page-slug/`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please explain more.

Comment: as i said, i have a page example: site.com/slug123 

now, if i open `site.com/slug123/downloads` it still shows me the content of `site.com/slug123/` 

but opening `site.com/slug123/abc` shows 404 which is correct, 

not sure what love it has with `/slug123/downloads`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you or your developer must have set 301 redirection for site.com/slug123/downloads
to site.com/slug123. That's why when you are opening site.com/slug123/downloads; it is being redirected to site.com/slug123 and others are showing 404 error.

Check your .htaccess file or redirection is also set from Cpanel. I am sure you will find something there.